# Use $ϵ$, $δ$ to check if the function is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

How can I check through $ϵ$-$δ$ if this function is continuous?

$f:(-\infty; 0]\to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) = \begin{cases}\sin x: & x < 0  \\ 7 :& x=0 \end{cases}$

I think I should study the continuity at $0$, but I got stuck

I think that: $ |f(x)-f(0)| = |f(x)-7| = \begin{cases} |\sin x - 7|: & x < 0  \\ 0 :& x=0 
\end{cases}$

And
$ |\sin x -7 | \le 8$  ,  $|f(x)-7| < ϵ $

But how do I utilise
$|x| < δ$ here?

Thank you so much!

Comment: "I think I should study the continuity at 0". No, you can't; this function is *not* continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry, i think i worded it wrong. I have to verify if this function is continuous or not.Then how can i show that it is not continuous at x=0 throught this theorem?

Comment: However, the function is continuous at any value $x < 0$.  Perhaps you have omitted pertinent details in the problem description, such as only having to prove that $f(x)$ is continuous for any $x < 0$.  If that is the case, you have some options about how to attack $f(x) = \sin(x)$ for example the Taylor series around $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Given that the function is not defined on $x > 0$, you are (apparently) being asked to prove that as $x$ approaches $0$ from below (ie. $x \to 0^-$), that $f(x)$ does not approach $f(0)$.  This implies that you have to establish that the negation of the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of continuity holds.  This means that you have to find some single fixed value of $\epsilon$, so that no matter how small that you specify $\delta$, you will be able to find at least one value of $x$ in a neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $0$ [limited to $x < 0]$ such that $|f(x) - f(0)| > \epsilon.$

Comment: @saltyvinegar: thanks for your comment. Please edit the title of your question as well.

Comment: @user2661923, this is a really good hint thank you!but, what if i show that $|f(x) - f(0)| \le  \epsilon$, where epsilon is fixed. is that still still valid? (considering that it should be true for all  $\epsilon > 0$)

Comment: You mean that if you choose $\epsilon = 287$ and then show that for all $x, |f(x) - f(0)| < 287$, then $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$.  No, that idea represents a misinterpretation of how to negate the definition of continuity.  Take a piece of scratch paper and write down the definition of continuity, in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.  Then, take a 2nd piece of paper and try to write down the negation of the definition that is on the first piece of paper.  Then (and only then), re-read my last comment before this comment.

Comment: What i was trying to say is: if i showed that $|f(x) - f(0)| \le 8$ would that mean the function is NOT continuous at x = $0$?
(because it would be continuous if $|f(x) - f(0)| < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon=1$. Then for any $\delta>0$, there exists $x\in(0-\delta,0)$ such that
$$
|f(x)-f(0)|=|\sin (x)-7|\geq 7-|\sin(x)|\ge 6 >\epsilon\;
$$
This shows that $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: $|\sin(x) - 7| = |7 - \sin(x)| = 7 + |\sin(x)|,~$ when $\sin(x) < 0$.